# How would you reset radio inputs onClick? ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, radio-button

Everything works fine, onClick the filters are removed and reset, but the radio inputs do not get removed. How would one go about resetting the radio inputs?

```
....
....

const [filters, setFilters] = useContext(FilterContext);

const toggleSelection = (e) => {
    setFilters((prevFilters) => ({
      ...prevFilters,
      [e.name]: e.id,
    }));
  };

const resetFilters = () => {
    setFilters({
      guest: 0,
      value: [200, 500],
      type: "",
      bed: "",
      view: "",
    });
  };

return (
...
...
<Categorie>
  <h3>Type</h3>
  <Selector>
    <Selection
     type="radio"
     name="type"
     id="room"
     onClick={(e) => toggleSelection(e.target)}
    />
    <SelectionLabel htmlFor="room">room</SelectionLabel>
    <Selection
     type="radio"
     name="type"
     id="suite"
     onClick={(e) => toggleSelection(e.target)}
    />
    <SelectionLabel htmlFor="suite">suite</SelectionLabel>
  </Selector>
</Categorie>


...
...


<Categorie>
  <Selection id="reset" onClick={resetFilters} />
  <SelectionLabel htmlFor="reset">reset</SelectionLabel>
</Categorie>

)
```

I've looked around, messed around with the checked property but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? Unselect them?

Comment: yes, removing the selections

Answer (score 0):

You can try [useRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). The idea is to create a reference to your radio inputs so you can control them through it. Here is some code:

```
....
....

const [filters, setFilters] = useContext(FilterContext);
const radioRef = useRef();
...
```

Assign it to the element:

```
    <Selection
     ref={radioRef}
     type="radio"
     name="type"
     id="room"
     onClick={(e) => toggleSelection(e.target)}
    />
```

Then just use it like so:

```
radioRef.current.checked = false;
```

This will uncheck the radio button linked to `radioRef`.

Here is a very basic Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-fermi-y59mf?file=/src/App.js

Note that this will work on a naked `<input ...` element. Since you seems to be using some framework, there might be a problem with this approach, but I doubt there will be.

Comment: Ahh I tried this before but I must've mistyped the refs lol, thanks

Comment: It works fine for single input. But how to do it for multiple inputs?